# Select nsdictionary key values when cell clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

This is my nsdictionary output from server side.names are on tableview but when user click on some cell i want to capture id of that dictionary

```
(
    {
    id = 1;
    name = "hair Dressing";
},
    {
    id = 2;
    name = Manicure;
},
    {
    id = 3;
    name = Cosmetics;
},
    {
    id = 4;
    name = "Make-Up";
},
    {
    id = 5;
    name = Solar;
}
)
//this is how i am printing data on tableview
cell.textLabel.text=[[dict valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This is an array which contains dictionary objects.

Comment: r u sure u got the result in **cell.textLabel.text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting the Name details correctly in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method, then use below method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 NSLog(@"id==%@",[[dict valueForKey:@"id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

 }
```

else use this

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 NSLog(@"id==%@",[[yourArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]);

 }
```

Comment: tanx a lot my brother, I think u r new in iOS, do well, congrats